# Dismissing dialog on activity finish

Tags: android, android-dialog

In my app I have several activities one after the other. After my login screen I have Home screen and after that several screens. Now When user select device home button or power off button I want to display login screen when user again comes to my app and then Home screen. Rest all activity I am finishing it from my base class. Now till here I have done, My problem is when I show a dialog in some other activity and at that instance if user click on home or power button, then i am getting **WINDOW LEAKED EXCEPTION**.

[image]

Like I have TempActivity is displaying a dialog and user clicked home button so StoreActivity and TempActivity will finish but Dialog never got chance to be dismissed. So What would be the best way to deal with this situation.
Is there some better way to dismiss the dialog so that I don't get any exception.

Answer (score 2):

Override `onDestroy`, there, check whether the dialog is present, if so, dismiss it.

Answer (score 2):

dismiss() in onDestroy() doesn't solve this problem. Try to override activity.finish() like:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    if(mDialog != null) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
    super.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `Dialog` handle in a member object, then when you finish the top activities, dismiss the dialog first.

You could make this more neat by creating abstract `Activity` class (which all your activities extends), which dismisses possible dialog when calling `finish()`

Comment: thanks Niko, but thing is Dialog can be dismissed only on or before calling onSavedInstance in lifecycle which is just after onPause(). and activity finish is detected only on finish or onDestroy is called which is much later on lifecycle. :D

Comment: @random4Infinity what do you mean by "can be dismissed only [..] before onSavedInstance"? In my app I dismiss the `Dialog` in `onDestroy` and it works like a charm ;-)